# presenting two different login screens based on roles

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, forms-authentication

I was trying to figure out whether it would be possible to present two different login screens based on the authorization role. The requirement is simple. I have two roles say "admin" and "public". There are "Authorize" attributes marked all over my applications action methods for these two roles.

Now the requirements of my application specifies different login screens for "admin" and "public". The "admin" login screen is secured by an additional security code which is not required for "public" login screen. What I was looking for is some way to know who is trying to log in based on the Action method invoked. If the action method invoked is decorated by `Authorize[Roles="admin"]` then I would present the admin login screen, whereas if action method invoked is applied `Authorize[Roles="public"]` then I need to present the public login screen.

If the Login Screen is directly invoked then by default the public login screen would be presented.

It may sound a little weird but this is the scenario I am trying to figure out the solution for.

Comment: Is this not a paradox - How will you know the user's Role until they log in and how can you show them a log in screen until you know their Role?

Comment: @Widor, I think that what he needs is that if a non authenticated user tries to hit a controller action which requires the admin role, he need to be redirected to a different login screen than if he was trying to hit a controller action that required some other role.

Comment: @Nirvan Ah, I see that's fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a custom authorize attribute which will redirect to the proper `logon` action:

```
public class MyAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        var roles = Roles.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        if (roles.Contains("admin", StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new
            {
                controller = "account",
                action = "adminlogon",
                returnUrl = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl
            }));
        }
        else
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new
            {
                controller = "account",
                action = "logon",
                returnUrl = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl
            }));
        }
    }
}
```

and then decorate your controllers/actions with it:

```
[MyAuthorize(Roles = "admin")]
public ActionResult Foo()
{
    return View();
}

[MyAuthorize(Roles = "normaluser")]
public ActionResult Bar()
{
    return View();
}
```

Now if a non authenticated user tries to hit the Foo action he will be redirected to the `/account/adminlogon` action and if he tries to hit the Bar action he would be redirected to the `/account/logon` action. In both cases the current url will be passed as returnUrl parameter so that upon successful login the user could be brought to the page that he was initially trying to browse.

Comment: Darin, Your Solution works well. The MyAuthorize attribute handles the redirection to different login screens. Thanks very much.